# Why does the output in the C code start counting an array index from the number 1 and not 0?

Tags: c

So I've got this string in a  C code i got from a book which has a quote in it, followed by another string which has one word from that quote. When it tell the program to find the position of the substring, it starts counting from the number 1 and not 0. Why is this? Here is what i mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[]="No Time like the Present";
    char sub[]="Time";
    if (strstr(str, sub)== NULL)
    {
        printf("not found");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Index number found at %d",strstr(str,sub)-str);
    }
    return 0
}
```

So it'll say:
                                     Index found at number 3

But shouldn't it be printing index found at number 2, because you start from zero? Or can you sometimes start from the number 1??!

Comment: Try looking for "No". I bet it's at position 0. "Time" starts 3 characters later, so it starts at position 3.

Comment: Did you forget to count the space?

Comment: forgot ';' for `return 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it always starts at 0, space is also counted as a character here so output is 3 and not 2.

Answer (score 16):

No, it starts at zero:

```
No Time...
^^^^
0123
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse `index` and `length`. `Index` and `length` are different.

```
char[] str = "stackoverflow";
```

Length of `str` will return `13`.

Index of `'c'` in `str` will return `3`.